# How to include configuration from other file in .bashrc and .bash_profile?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I often use use aliases in terminal. But `alias` command is only effective until I close that session. So, I have to set aliases and variables in `.bashrc` so they are permanent. But I when use TTY console, `.bashrc` file is no more effective. Because login shells use the `.bash_profile` file and non-login shells like Gnome Terminal use the `.bashrc` file. So, I have to set those aliases and variables again in `.bash_profile` file. Is there any way to make a common file which will be included by both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` ? I have tried to make a common file named `.bash_commons` in the home directory. Then I added line the following line to both file:

```bsh
bash ~/bash_commons
```

But it failed as `bash` automatically unset any variables and aliases defined in scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another command which is `source` . It is a shell build-in command. It includes commands from another file in the bash script which is being executed. It's takes the file name as a argument and some other arguments like this (from `source --help` ):

```bsh
source filename [arguments]
```

Add this line to `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` file:

```bsh
source ~/.bash_commons
```

Now both Gnome Terminal (non-login shell and uses `.bashrc` ) and TTY console (login shell and uses `.bash_profile` ) will load commands from the file `.bash_commons` and aliases and variables will work in both Gnome Terminal and TTY console.

Comment: Your suggestion to add the source command inside .bashrc is correct. I suggest also to add around the command a check about the existance of the file: if [ -f ~/.bash_commons ]; then source ~/.bash_commons; fi